# How many people are killed in The Expendables 2?

Tags: the-expendables-2

I know that there was [203 people  killed](http://expendables.wikia.com/wiki/Kill_Count) in the Expendables.

But how many people were killed in the Expendables 2?

Comment: Give me 2 hours to answer.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini its 12 hours now :p

Comment: He might be watching the movie repeatedly to count the number of persons killed.!

Comment: This sounds very much like trivia.

Comment: Are kills made by Jet Li counted as half a kill?

Comment: Are Chuck Norris kills counted ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took a bit of digging - but it turned out that the most reliable source was the [Expendables Wiki](http://expendables.wikia.com/wiki/Kill_Count), which claims that the final body count was **489**.